# latexdiff problems with SCfigure

Tags: floats, latexdiff

When I use latexdiff on documents with SCfigures that have changed slightly, for example in size, they appear twice such that the caption has no space and messes up the formatting.

For figures this does not happen.

How can I make SCfigures be treated same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by adding the `SCfigure` to the `PICTUREENV` via the option

```
--config="PICTUREENV=(?:picture|figure|DIFnomarkup|SCfigure)[\w\d*@]*"
```

I have made a feature request to have this setting as default here:

https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/issues/57